# How can I make jQuery find the element if the string placement is random in my selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If my HTML were to be

```
<h1>Hi My Name Is John</h1>
```

How would I make jQuery find this h1 element if I searched for `Name` and `John`?

If I use `:contains` and do `$("h1:contains('Name John')")` it won't find the element. It will only find the element if it's an exact match so it would be `$("h1:contains('Name Is John')")`

How can I make jQuery find the element if the string placement is random in my selector?

I've also gotten this to work, but this only works if it's an exact match

```
var aray = retrievedData; //This has strings stored in an array
    $("h1").each(function(i, that) {

        var key1 = aray[0];
        var key2 = aray[1];
        var key3 = aray[2];
        var thisText = $(this).text();
        if (thisText.includes(`${key1}`) || thisText.includes(`${key2}`) || thisText.includes(`${key3}`)) {
            //do something
            console.log(($(this).text()));
        }
    });
```

Is there also a way to store these strings in an array and then loop the `:contains` or `&&` through the `h1`?

So if I were to have

```
<h1>Hi My Name is John</h1>
<h1>I like to eat spaghetti</h1>
```

And I stored `Name John` and `like spaghetti`, how can I make jQuery automatically make a function for these specific strings and then loop through the `h1`?

Comment: Can you string two contains together? eg `contains('Name'):contains('John')` ? (Note: I genuinely don't know if this is possible... but it's where I'd start googling)

Comment: So split on whitespace and loop over the array and build the selector

Comment: @epascarello How would I build the selector for each match though?

Comment: You do not know how to loop and build a string?

Comment: Could you give an example? @epascarello

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could you loop through all the `h1` and check with `&&` and condition.

```
$("h1").each(function(){
   if($(this).text().indexOf("Name")=='-1' && $(this).text().indexOf("John")=='-1')
   {
      //YOUR CODE HERE...
   }
});
```

Edit :
From what I understood :p,
checking all the words in each sentence(string) in the array,
If it matches with anything in any `<h1>` it will select it.

```
var arr = ["Name John","Hello World"];
$("h1").each(function(){
     for(var s= 0 ; s < arr.length ; s++)
     {
         let a1 = arr[s];
         a1 = a1.split(" ");
         let a2 = $(this).text().trim().split(" ");
         var z = $.map(a1,function(a){return $.inArray(a, a2) < 0 ? null : a;})
         if(z.length > 0)
         {
              //H1 contains some word in it 
         }
     }
});
```

Comment: I do, but in the way I did it before, I could only find the element by searching for 1 word or the whole sentence. Your solution works by searching for 2 words using &&. I'm trying to store strings in an array and then use that instead of manually typing it in the code

Comment: @xSketchy0 So you want to search for each word in the sentences at each array position right?

Comment: Yeah so If I added the string `Name John` and string `like spaghetti` to an array, I want it to loop through all the `h1`'s and use the values in the array in the if statement you made

Comment: @xSketchy0 Check the edit. I am not quite clear about the question, have given it a try...
Also, you should look at underscore.js if you are dealing a lot in arrays!

Comment: Ooo underscore.js looks interesting! However I've tried your code, tested it on my project, but it says `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).text.trim is not a function` Do you know why?

Comment: Damn, add a () after `text`. Edited in the answer as well @xSketchy0
Can try it without trim as well

Comment: Alright so I've been testing it again, It kind of works the way I want it to, but not quite yet. For example: If I have an `<h1>Thermal Black</h1>` and `<h1>Thermal Heather Grey</h1>` and if I only have `var arr = ["Thermal Grey"];`, the code returns both `h1`'s instead of only the `h1` with the value `Thermal Heather Grey`. Is there any way I can make it only return the `h1` if all the words match in the string I saved in the array

Comment: Hey I had one more question. If I have `<h1>Dark Black</h1>` and `<h1>Light Black</h1>` and Store `Dark Black` in my array, how can I make it only return the first h1 instead of both since they both contain Black.

Comment: @xSketchy0 Wont that depend whether how they are placed in the DOM?

Comment: I don't think the order matters. I feel like it searches for each individual word when saving 1 string in the array with multiple words

Comment: Yeah so the `a1 = a1.split(" ");` splits each word in the string saved in the array and then it searches for each word and if any of the `h1` match it'll return them. I'm trying to make it match the whole string and if all of the words as a whole don't match the `h1`, it won't return anything

Comment: @xSketchy0 Yes I think am getting your point..you have both the arrays select the smaller array and then...instead of the $.map you would have to actually have some sort of a flag variable to loop and see through the bigger array if it contains all of the small array values...
Could do something like this ?

Comment: Yeah so if I have `<h1>Pastel Dark Black</h1>` and `<h1>Pastel Dark Grey</h1>` and I've got `Pastel Black` in my array, `.split()` splits `Pastel` and `Black` and searches for both and if any of the `h1`'s match (it will find both, because the `h1`'s both contain `Pastel` ) it'll return that. What I want my code to do is that if `Pastel` and `Black` aren't in the same `h1` element, it shouldn't return anything other than the `h1` that does contain both words. Although I have no idea how to implement that haha. I'm a novice

Comment: @xSketchy0 Ok this is a wild guess, can you try changing the if condition from `if(z.length > 0)` to `if(z.length >= arr[s].length)` and check...

Comment: Ah this doesn't return anything @Varun

Comment: @xSketchy0 One more!
before the `if` declare a variable like... 
`let t = ((a1.length > a2.length) ? a1.length : a2.length);`
and then the if condition like `if(z.length >= t)`

Comment: Still doesn't return anything :/ Can we bring this to a chat or something, because I really want this to work @Varun EDIT: It only returns if the string is the exact same as the h1, so it defeats the purpose of what I want it to do

Comment: Sure, at work right now, will be free in some time, till then can you put this code online somewhere, a fiddle maybe...
Where i could run it and see

Comment: @xSketchy0 Damnnn..i just messed up the ternary operator, flipped the values.It works now as you want it to IMO
Check this :
https://jsfiddle.net/yfazeexx/2/

Comment: @xSketchy0 The ternary operator was supposed to be `let t = ((a1.length > a2.length) ? a2.length : a1.length);` and 1 more thing , inside the if you need to use `$(this)` and not `this`

Comment: So I tried out the fiddle you just sent, and I just switched the `console.log($(this))` with `$(this).css("color","yellow")`, added "Yellow" to the array and I added another `h1` with "Yellow Green" in it. How come it doesn't change the `h1` with Yellow Green to yellow? Your code does work, but it only works for the first string in the array

Comment: Scrap everything I said about the fiddle, it does work, but for some reason it doesn't work locally on my project. I think there's something going wrong with me saving the items to the localStorage and getting it as an array

Comment: Oh got it working!, Apparently if I saved the value of an input like this `Word1, Word2`, the space after the comma would save the array like this: `["Word1", " Word2"]` which ruined the array. I fixed it by changing my `.split(",");` to `.split(", ");`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$("h1:contains('Name'):contains('John')")
```

Comment: This works, I've added some more questions to my post

Comment: This is now confusing, I don't understand the new question